# Crash on Windows Store App launch on certain PCs(Bing Maps)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, bing-maps, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

When I test my App on other PC(not the one with which I'm developing), it crashes on startup. I've observed that crash occurs only with PCs without Visual Studio installed on it.

I'm using Bing Maps SDK in my app, so the problem is probably related to this: [discussion of the problem -> see Q&A section.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca)

I've tried compiling in Release, but the problem persists. Is there any workaround, or we should just stand here, waiting to MS to release new version of SDK?

UPD: Seems like VS don't leave Bing Map SDK binaries in Dependencies folder of App package. How one force VS to include binaries in build?

UPD2: Problem solved - it wasn't Bing Maps fault, but an error in my code. Never blame other before you're 100% sure about yourself ;)

Comment: Most probably your app is missing some DLL's that Visual studio installs. Try to run your app in WinDbg - install it on a machine that does not have VS, and run your app. Debug version is more preferable.
Most of the time it is some MS Runtime libraries that needed to be installed.

Comment: Have you made sure you have updated the Bing SDK to the RTM version? You can easily do that within VS extensions.

Comment: @MattiasLindberg: yes, Bing SDK is up to date(10/19/2012 release).

Comment: @artapet: is there a way of debugging windows store apps with windbg?

Comment: @dtumaykin And during Creation of your package you have executed "Launch Windows App Certification Kit" to make sure there are no issues?

Comment: @MattiasLindberg, yes, app passes certification without warnings

Comment: @dtumaykin Did you add a reference to Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package in your application? Bing Maps SDK is a native library AFAIK.

Comment: @DamirArh, yes, I've added them. Anyway the problem is solved :) Thanks for your time.